# Protocol buffers inheritance

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is there a way to make a proto file that will extend a existing proto file? For example include google's openrtb [proto file](https://github.com/google/openrtb/blob/master/openrtb-core/src/main/protobuf/openrtb.proto) in a new proto file which will inherit the current file objects, and change other sections of the file, like defining new enum fields (overriding existing enums).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions I don't think that's what you want though. You can import other definitions and wrap them. But extending existing types that aren't meant to be extended is afaik a nono. You can edit the original though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, modifying the original is a problem because including the openrtb-core.jar has already included the compiled proto. Is there a way to hide the class? I tried to use generics but the type class needs to extend the original class and that is not possible.